# Character map broken during FTP transfer

Tags: linux, ftp, charset

I have recently migrated a web server running an old PHP shop, which runs a little tricky: let me explain first. If you want to post that on thedailywtf or codinghorror, you're welcome.

The shop owner runs an exe on his own machine to update the products. The program generates (from an MDB Access database) its own PHP files, and finally uploads them to the target server, together with a special `updatedb.php` and a `db.sql` file (that is accessible publicly from the `wwwroot`). The exe file then invokes a `POST` to `updatedb.sql` with a security parameter that prevents foreign people to invoke the PHP script (I won't explain which public text file holds the secret code in its first line).

What does the PHP do then? Just clear the DB and re-insert all the data, even if actual shop page don't load their data from MySQL but each generated PHP file contains static description and image links. The `updatedb.php` loads data from the `db.sql` file and runs each and every line in a new SQL connection.

### Configuration differences

Old and new server both run `Apache 2` and `vsftpd`. I found that the locale is different between the two: old uses `ISO-8859-15` charmap and new server `UTF-8`.
The `vsftpd` configuration is identical

### The charset problem

I found that most non-ASCII symbols (like `€`uro, `°` and accented letters `àèéìòù`) got screwed up so they won't run in SQL statements (and you may guess that no escaping is done, and I can confirm that!)

### The question

Since the customer doesn't want to trash their shop, forcing me to add several special PHP configuration directives for their vhost, how do I fix the character encoding for files transferred over FTP?

I thought about configuration in `vsftpd.conf` ([source](http://vsftpd.devnet.ru/vsftpd/tags/vsFTPd-2.0.3-ext.3/vsftpd.conf))

```
# Enable character convertion. Supported UTF-8 (Russian chars) = UTF8,
# Win-1251 = WIN1251 or 1251, Koi8-r = KOI8R or 878, IBM 866 = DOS or 866.
convert_charset_enable=1
# Define charset local
local_charset=UTF8
# Define default charset on remote host
remote_charset=ISO-8859-15
```

But forcing remote charset to iso-8859-15 doesn't seem great. Fortunately, that's the only customer who use FTP transfers from Windows XP.

[Update] I just found my old question [Euro character messed up during FTP transfer](https://serverfault.com/questions/458340/euro-character-messed-up-during-ftp-transfer) about a similar problem. In that case, it was SQL strings being cut from the € sign. Now it's the queries being executed with a messed up € sign.

Comment: I have also tried creating a file with lots of accents and transferring it using Xftp client with *default* settings: letters were fine

Comment: Are the files being transferred in binary or ascii mode?

Comment: Not sure but I suppose ASCII

Comment: If you somehow can force the process to transfer as binary you may avoid the problems with the character transformations. Just be aware that switching to binary will keep the Windows line breaks (CR+LF) in the file, where ASCII mode may have changed that into only LF. So it may be that the updatedb.php need to take that into account.

Comment: I was thinking about using an SSH bridge like Bitvise. It worked in a previous installation like a charm